# I'm thousands, millions... that you hate

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I'm thousands, millions that you hate
>   but none when you date.
>   Kill me never early nor never late
>   as I always come back great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's

> dust

I'm thousands, millions that you hate

> Dust is everywhere, not a good thing, we hate it

but none when you date.

> We take extra good care to clean up everything before a date

Kill me never early nor never late

> You can't clean it too early, it will get dusted again, nor too late (duh!)

as I always come back great.

> No matter how many times you clean something it will get dust on it again.

Answer (score 11):

A somewhat comical attempt:

> Pubic hair

I'm thousands, millions that you hate

> So many individual hairs, and so itchy!

but none when you date.

> Many shave when they expect someone to see!

Kill me never early nor never late

> Too early or late in the day and you may be tired and cut yourself...

as I always come back great.

> Hair comes back if cut by traditional means.

Comment: In the context of dating, kill me never early could mean shaving too early would result in regrowth and never late could mean that shaving after the date is obviously too late... I'm not sure but it might fit a little better than feeling tired

Comment: The typical human **head** has no more than 150k hairs, so the ”millions” bit sure sounds scary.

Comment: @Bass Well, maybe the answer should be changed to Neanderthal rot13(chovp unvef), then?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the OP's name, I guess it is:

> Hair

I'm thousands, millions that you hate

> For ladies, hairs is a pain to deal with

but none when you date.

> When you're dating, it became a...weapon of attraction?

Kill me never early nor never late

> Referring to haircut

as I always come back great.

> Hair growth back fast enough

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about :

> Hairs on a woman's leg

*I'm thousands, millions that you hate*

> I think this is just an exaggeration (maybe OP is a yeti?). Anyway, there are lots of hairs growing on our legs

*but none when you date*

> As lots of other users have already noticed, generally speaking when dating we try to get rid of our superfluous hairs! And I think we are specifically talking about women's hairs, so this is even more "relevant"

*Kill me never early nor never late*

> If you are anything like my girlfriend, you will always wait till the last second to do it!

*as I always come back great*

> There is a "legend" that says that every time you cut your hair, they will grow back stronger!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is:

> Weeds

I'm thousands, millions that you hate

> People with lawns can hate weeds.

but none when you date

> Weeds sometimes have flowers, which could be useful.

Kill me never early nor never late

> There are certian times when it is best to spray weeds.

as I always come back great

> Weeds are hard to get rid of.

Answer (score 0):

a potential answer can be

> Mosquitoes.

I'm thousands, millions that you hate

> Mosquitoes as everyone knows are millions in number and almost everyone hate them.

but none when you date.

> Usually a person goes on a date to a clean place such as restaurants hotels etc.,where they pay special attention to all these things and have mosquitoes/fly killers and catchers installed in there premises so as to provide a better customer experience.

Kill me never early nor never late

> An average person uses mosquitoes repellents when they notice the growth, in there surroundings which can include sprays , coils,creams etc. As it is difficult to detect them at an early stage. And if they are  killed late then they can make a person ill.

as I always come back great.

> Even if we succeed in getting a relief from these creatures sooner or late they again come back from some place or the other especially in hot and humid areas in an even greater number.

Answer (score 0):

A rather dark and cynical attempt.  Are you

> People

I'm thousands, millions that you hate

> There are billions of people in the world, one cannot like all of them.

but none when you date.

> you should find someone to date that you don't hate.

Kill me never early nor never late

> One should never kill people, early or late!

as I always come back great.

> great as in large - there is a very large population of people.

Answer (score 0):

They may be

> Bad scents/smells/odours

I'm thousands, millions that you hate

> Not sure if anyone knows exactly how many of them they hate, but there could sure be that many, especially when counting recurring versions

but none when you date.

> Most people freshen up before going on a date, making sure they don't carry any

Kill me never early nor never late

> They are "killed" when they are hated, but no point doing so early (e.g. while still working out) nor late (e.g. halfway through your date?), best to do so at exactly the right time

as I always come back great.

> Eventually they will come back great, as in that they're great in coming back. But this could also mean that when they are "killed" they are often fought/replaced by a great version instead